# User can't write in textarea

Tags: html

Sorry if I can't explain this but I don't know how to do it.

My problem is that when user write in the textarea input everything its ok, but when user resize the screen can't write in the textarea doesn't matter where user click the input do not respond.

[Here is the example](http://www.bootply.com/UEuYJBGou5)

If you don't understand me, just open the link and write something in the textarea, then resize the window and try to write in the textarea and there is the problem.

Comment: You have DIV with `.col-md-3.hidden-print` which is over the textarea on small devices, you can add `col-sm-3` class that will make it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go buddy!

[Working!](http://www.bootply.com/AABUpd76gZ)

I just remove this divs with this structure:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
```

I think that its no necessary create another div with the same col class.